# Mysql: TRIGGER using SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql, triggers, substring

I'm trying to create a TRIGGER that inserts a new row for every substring updated in a column, let's say I have an entry with substring separated by a comma, which would be like

> foo,bar,bar,foo

and for every comma I want to insert a new row into "table2" 
so i would have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'test' AFTER UPDATE ON 'database.table1'
FOR EACH ROW IF (NEW.entry != OLD.entry) THEN
    INSERT INTO table2
        ('id_entry', 'sub_entry')
    VALUES
        (NEW.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX('NEW.entry',',',n+1))
END IF
```

Of course this is not correct and I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: databases are not made for those things. You should not store multiple values in a single column

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the single quote around var in substr

```
  (NEW.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.entry,',',n+1))
```